# Distributed System Random Number Generator

Tags: random, soa, distributed

This may have to be more of a statistical/mathematical question, especially given the general nature of it. I'll move it if need be, but feedback is greatly appreciated.

I am very curious what the potential impact to a random number generator would be in a SOA design. For the sake of argument, let's assume a well seeded and design generator, with no issues and a perfectly random generation capability.

Within the full set of numbers created by this generator we see perfect randomness. **But what happens when the consuming applications are distributed, and multiple remote hosts request a random number? Will it still be random to the host?**

It seems like there is at least a potential reduction in the variability of the randomness, since each host will be taking a subset of the randomly generated numbers. And as such it could, by chance/coincidence create a more or less structured pattern. The pattern would only exist on a host by host basis, while the overall system would still seem to be generating perfectly random results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'd really generate random numbers, than any subset of those numbers would still be random.

Now since that isn't possible, what happens if you would take the random number generators which are used for security purposes like encryption (since those have more sophisticated algorithms than the simple generators)? I see two scenarios:

1. Your clients will talk to the server in the same order. So 10 clients means you get every 10th generated number. People could try to take those numbers and figure out the configuration of the random number generator. But they can do it also when they see all the numbers. And if any subset of those generators would be predictable, it wouldn't be useful for encryption anymore, so here you can argue that they still want any subset to be as well random.
2. Your clients will act completely independently and access the server in random orders. Here you actually get real randomness (if it is for instance based on user input) and therefore even badly designed pseudo random generators could give you a better random distribution on each client. Since those don't know if they are getting the next number of the generator or the 100th.

Comment: Sounds good thanks, the second point makes great sense, since the numbers should be random to each client when accessed from different (random) points in time and the generator iterations. I was assuming a  Tausworth LFG.